# Gatsby 3rd party scripts not working as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

I have the problem with including fastspring to my gatsby project. Problem is the following: I add the script in html head but it doesn't work on all pages(it works only if I refresh the page)
I tried to fix that by inserting script in html.js, with gatsby-ssr.js and gatsby-browser.js

gatsby-browser.js
[image]

I put the same code in gatsby-ssr.js, I have also tried with Helmet but nothing works for me
I want it to work on all the pages without needing to refresh the page, so if somebody could help me with this. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Instead of including your script into html, better `require()`/`import` it from your top-level javascript module, something like `src/pages/index.js` - Webpack, used by Gatsby under the hood, will include it into the bundle.

Comment: @BorisBurkov so if I understand it correctly, I should include it in e.g. index.js ? With helmet or without helmet?

Comment: @BorisBurkov this way it only works on index.js page and only the first time, if I go to other page and then return to the index.js (homepage) it doesn't work without the refresh :/ maybe i'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry, was AFK. Do you have any custom component that is rendered on all the pages of your website? For instance, I have a `layout.js` component that is the parent of all the other pages. I'd try importing your script there. Though, your initial approach with `html.js` and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` seems like a more idiomatic solution.

Comment: @BorisBurkov I've put it in layout.js then it only works on initial load and never again not even after refreshing the page

Comment: @BorisBurkov The page delivered both an 'X-Frame-Options' header and a 'Content-Security-Policy' header with a 'frame-ancestors' directive. Although the 'X-Frame-Options' header alone would have blocked embedding, it has been ignored.

Comment: Interesting. What if you dropped all the wrapper, the `onRenderBody` and `setHeadComponents` calls and just said something like `import faststring-builder` in `layout.js`? Or does `faststring-builder.min.js` necessarily require a proper `<script>` tag to function, like if it's using jsonp: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP?

Comment: @BorisBurkov the tag should be exactly as it is on the screenshot, I don't know if it would work any other way, I'm kinda new with gatsby so maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Feels like your solution is an idiomatic, feels like you did everything as intended. As for the works-only-on-first-load problem, maybe, try checking various caches of your browser, possibly, service workers as well.

Comment: @BorisBurkov would it help if I give you the ip to my website?

Comment: I've taken a look at my own Gatsby blog. It doesn't use neither service workers, nor other new caching options, only cookies, session and local storage. You can check it by yourself e.g. in Chrome Developer Tools -> Application tab. I don't think that IP would help much, but if you could provide some helpful links to information about `fastspring-builder.min.js`, it might help.

Comment: @BorisBurkov https://fastspring.com/docs/storefronts/ here is about storefront, actually here is the all the documentation about fastspring, and also here is the video where they show you how to include it in regular htm,css and js page https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffRjNM31IXw , I hope this will be somewhat helpful

Comment: Thanks for the links. I think it might make sense to try a different approach and integrate fastspring with React directly, as described in this repo: https://github.com/gurschitz/use-fastspring. Maybe try inserting the component from that repo into your `layout` component? Also, there is a set of lower-level APIs that you may use directly with React lifecycle hooks like `componentDidMount`or your custom event handlers: https://fastspring.com/docs/access-the-library-with-javascript/.

Comment: @BorisBurkov thank you so much for helping , I'll try that later today and come back with feedback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233751/discussion-between-demigod98-and-boris-burkov).

Comment: @BorisBurkov Would it be possible to get in contact with you via discord or some social media so you review my code or that would be a problem?

Comment: I could take a quick look. I'm available in telegram. Are you somewhat knowledgable in React?

Comment: Could you send me the link to your telegram account then?About my knowledge about react, well I’m pretty new at gatsby/react, better to say it’s my first project in it, I get the basic concepts, but still have lot to learn, so some words and tips from someone experienced would mean the world to me. I hope that won’t be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an old issue, but someone might still have the problem.
I did search for a solution to it for some time and in the end, I went with the following.

1. I created a component called FastSpringStoreApi.js. It loads FastSpring API and subscribes to 2 callback events from it - `data-popup-closed` and `data-data-callback`. I used this two to dispatch custom js events for which I listen in my FastSpring provider. These 2 events contain all information needed for store to function (items, pricing, cart information)

*Note: there is a reason I save data into sessionStorage. The event can be dispatched before React hydrates. And in cases like this I take data in session storage as initial state in my reducers.*

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  FS_EVENTS,
  FS_SESSION_KEY
} from './FastSpringStore.keys';

export default ({ storeFrontId }) => (
  <>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML= {{
        __html:`
          function raiseFSPopupCloseEvent(data) {
            var popupCloseEvent = new CustomEvent(
             '${FS_EVENTS.POPUP_CLOSE}',
             { detail: data }
            );
            window.dispatchEvent(popupCloseEvent);
          }
          
          function raiseFSDataUpdateEvent(data) {
            var dataUpdateEvent = new CustomEvent(
             '${FS_EVENTS.DATA_UPDATE}',
             { detail: data }
            );
            
            window
              .sessionStorage
              .setItem(
                '${FS_SESSION_KEY}',
                 JSON.stringify(data)
               )
              
            window.dispatchEvent(dataUpdateEvent);
          }
        `
      }}
    />
    <script
      id="fsc-api"
      src="https://d1f8f9xcsvx3ha.cloudfront.net/sbl/0.8.5/fastspring-builder.min.js"
      type="text/javascript"
      data-popup-closed="raiseFSPopupCloseEvent"
      data-data-callback="raiseFSDataUpdateEvent"
      data-continuous="true"
      data-storefront={storeFrontId}
    />
  </>
)
```

2. I load this component inside `gatsby-ssr.js` only

```js
export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }) => {
  setHeadComponents([
    <FastSpringStoreApi
      key="fast-spring-store-api"
      storeFrontId="..."
    />,
  ])
}
```

3. I have FasSpringStore provider where I subscribe to my fs events. Looks like this. With it I can get all data needed further down to any of the components.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const onPopupClosed = (data) => {
      // Popup was closed and order was finished (we have order id)
      if (_has(data.detail, 'id')) {
        // Navigate to home page
        // TODO: Show thank you page in the future
        navigate('/')
        dispatch(cleanShopStore())
      }
    }

    const onDataUpdate = (data) => {
      dispatch(
        setOrderInfo(
          mapFSDataToPayload(
            data.detail
          )
        )
      )
    }

    window.addEventListener(FS_EVENTS.POPUP_CLOSE, onPopupClosed, false);
    window.addEventListener(FS_EVENTS.DATA_UPDATE, onDataUpdate, false);


    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(FS_EVENTS.POPUP_CLOSE, onPopupClosed)
      window.removeEventListener(FS_EVENTS.DATA_UPDATE, onDataUpdate)
      window.sessionStorage.removeItem(FS_SESSION_KEY)
    }
  }, [])
```

4. Inside `gatsby-ssr.js` I wrap my root element with store provider

```js
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
  <FastSpringStoreProvider>
    {element}
  </FastSpringStoreProvider>
);
```

5. Same goes for `gatsby-browser.js`

```js
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
  <FastSpringStoreProvider>
    {element}
  </FastSpringStoreProvider>
);
```

Hope this gives some ideas for FastSpring implementation.